# Android:I dont understand why if block is always true here?

Tags: android, firebase

`

```
SimpleDateFormat curFormater = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
                        Date c = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
                        String formattedDate=curFormater.format(c);
                        Log.d("tag","formate: " + formattedDate);
                   imageDate=dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                        Log.d("date","date: " + imageDate);
                        if (imageDate==formattedDate) {
                            Toast.makeText(accountantFunctions.this, "only 1 image upload is allowed per day", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            cameraBtn.setEnabled(false);
                        }else{
                            askCameraPermissions();
                        }
```

`

```
 The logcat is showing this:
    D/ColorViewRootUtil: nav gesture mode swipeFromBottom ignore false downY 1564 mScreenHeight 2340 mScreenWidth 1080 mStatusBarHeight 54 globalScale 1.125 nav mode 3 event MotionEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, actionButton=0, id[0]=0, x[0]=407.0, y[0]=1564.0, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, classification=NONE, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=260828295, downTime=260828295, deviceId=4, source=0x1002, displayId=0 } rotation 0
    D/tag: key: vikashbhushan189@gmail.com
    D/date: date: https://accounting-book-5401b.firebaseio.com/Accountantuser/vikashbhushan189%40gmail%2Ccom/timestamp
    D/tag: formate: 20200229
    D/date: date: 20200228
```

Here I am getting imageDate from firebase realtime database.
Whenever i run if condition always remains false, and a`skCameraPermissions();` is called up ever time.

Comment: Please provide more context.

Answer (score 1):

When comparing, always keep that in mind.

`==` is used for **Reference Equality**.

`.equals()` is used to check if **contents** of both objects are **Equal/Same**

In your case as you are **comparing contents**, you should be using:

```
if (imageDate.equals(formattedDate)) {
    Toast.makeText(accountantFunctions.this, "only 1 image upload is allowed per day", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    cameraBtn.setEnabled(false);
} else {
    askCameraPermissions();
}
```

For more understanding between **==**  *vs* **.equals()** , please have a look to this answer
[== vs .equals()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767372/string-equals-versus)

Comment: @vikash, I hope my answer helped you.

Comment: if it worked don't forget to accept the answer, so that other's can also take benefit from your problem.

Answer (score 0):

To compare **String** type you need to use **equals()** method

**Solution** -

```
if (imageDate.equals(formattedDate)) {
}
```